# Node.js serial port on windows Access denied

Tags: windows, node.js, serial-port

I have following error while running short program:

```
events.js:2817: Uncaught Error: Opening \\.\COM1: Access denied
```

my program is just to try to open the port and see what is it working:

```
var SerialPort = require("serialport").SerialPort;

var serialPort = new SerialPort('COM1',{baudrate: 9600}, true);


serialPort.on ('open', function () {
    console.log("Open");
    serialPort.write(0x05);
    serialPort.on ('data', function( data ) {
        console.log("data" + data.toString());
    });
});
```

I am using USB to COM adapter that is set on COM1.

Comment: Does the problem go away if you run this as administrator in a command prompt with elevated privileges?  Also, this may relate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153547/access-to-the-port-com1-is-denied

Comment: I needed to close the port. Now it works.

Comment: I'm having this problem and it is not going away. If I do a serialPort.close() it reports that the port is not currently open. In the port list() the port is shown. It's on a Windows 7 laptop.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
var serialPort = new SerialPort('\\\\.\\COM1', {baudrate: 9600}, true);
```

This worked magic for me!